# Can't get function call to work in PHP

Tags: php, json

I'm having trouble with getting JSON data using a `$.getJSON`request. In one PHP document I have my function. The code is:

```
function get_topchart($dbc, $var_ziekenhuis_id, $var_department_id) {

    if($var_department_id == "Not Entered") {

        $query = "SELECT afdeling, ligduur as ld FROM datavoorbeeld WHERE ziekenhuis='$var_hospital_id' ORDER BY afdeling DESC";
        $result = mysqli_query($dbc,$query);

        $data = array();
        while ( $row = $result->fetch_assoc() ) {
          $data[] = $row;
        }
        echo json_encode( $data );
        //return(json_encode( $data ));

    } else {

        $query = "SELECT afdeling, ligduur as ld FROM datavoorbeeld WHERE ziekenhuis='$var_hospital_id' and afdeling='$var_department_id' ORDER BY afdeling DESC";
        $result = mysqli_query($dbc,$query);

        $data = array();
        while ( $row = $result->fetch_assoc() ) {
          $data[] = $row;
        }
        echo json_encode( $data );
        //return(json_encode( $data ));
    }
}
```

I'm using the following code to call the above function which is in getcharts.php:

```
<?php 
session_start();

include('../functions/datafunctions.php'); 
include('../config/db.php');


if(!isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
    header('Location: ../login.php');
}

//Determine the function that should be called
$var_function_id = $_GET['funcid'];
//Set variables
$var_ziekenhuis_id = $_GET['hosp'];
$var_department_id = $_GET['dept'];

switch ($var_function_id) {
    case "top_chart":
        //Call function
        get_topchart($dbc, $var_ziekenhuis_id, $var_department_id);
    case "bottom_chart":
        //New code here 
}
?>
```

The `$.getJSON` i use is:

```
$.getJSON('functions/getcharts.php', {
    "hosp":hospital,
    "dept":department,
    "funcid":functionid},
```

When i skip the whole getcharts.php and use the switch function directly, things do work. That code is:

```
<?php 

session_start();
include('../config/db.php');

//Controleer eerst of gebruiker succesvol is ingelogd:

if(!isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
    header('Location: ../login.php');
}

//Determine the function that should be called
$var_function_id = $_GET['funcid'];
//Set variables
$var_hospital_id = $_GET['hosp'];
$var_department_id = $_GET['dept'];

switch ($var_function_id) {
    case "top_chart":

        //function get_topchart($dbc, $var_ziekenhuis_id, $var_department_id) {

            if($var_department_id == "Not Entered") {

                $query = "SELECT afdeling, ligduur as ld FROM datavoorbeeld WHERE ziekenhuis='$var_hospital_id' ORDER BY afdeling DESC";
                $result = mysqli_query($dbc,$query);

                $data = array();
                while ( $row = $result->fetch_assoc() ) {
                  $data[] = $row;
                }
                echo json_encode( $data );
                //return(json_encode( $data ));

            } else {

                $query = "SELECT afdeling, ligduur as ld FROM datavoorbeeld WHERE ziekenhuis='$var_hospital_id' and afdeling='$var_department_id' ORDER BY afdeling DESC";
                $result = mysqli_query($dbc,$query);

                $data = array();
                while ( $row = $result->fetch_assoc() ) {
                  $data[] = $row;
                }
                echo json_encode( $data );
                //return(json_encode( $data ));
            }
        //}
}

?>
```

The `$getJSON` code in that case is:

```
$.getJSON('functions/datafunctions.php', {
    "hosp":hospital,
    "dept":department,
    "funcid":functionid},
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
echo json_encode( $data );
```

with

```
return json_encode( $data );
```

Replace

```
switch ($var_function_id) {
    case "top_chart":
        //Call function
        get_topchart($dbc, $var_ziekenhuis_id, $var_department_id);
    case "bottom_chart":
        //New code here 
}
```

with:

```
switch ($var_function_id) {
    case "top_chart":
        //Call function
        echo get_topchart($dbc, $var_ziekenhuis_id, $var_department_id);
    case "bottom_chart":
        //New code here 
}
```

Comment: Many thanks! I also found out that in the SQL statement i was using the wrong variable. Now things are working.

Comment: @CostCare read http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: @CostCare, please accept my answer if you feel it fixed your issue, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Uncomment the return statement to your function : 
function get_topchart($dbc, $var_ziekenhuis_id, $var_department_id) {

```
if($var_department_id == "Not Entered") {

    $query = "SELECT afdeling, ligduur as ld FROM datavoorbeeld WHERE ziekenhuis='$var_hospital_id' ORDER BY afdeling DESC";
    $result = mysqli_query($dbc,$query);

    $data = array();
    while ( $row = $result->fetch_assoc() ) {
      $data[] = $row;
    }
    return(json_encode( $data ));

} else {

    $query = "SELECT afdeling, ligduur as ld FROM datavoorbeeld WHERE ziekenhuis='$var_hospital_id' and afdeling='$var_department_id' ORDER BY afdeling DESC";
    $result = mysqli_query($dbc,$query);

    $data = array();
    while ( $row = $result->fetch_assoc() ) {
      $data[] = $row;
    }
    return(json_encode( $data ));
}
```

}

And affect the return statement of your function on a variable when you call it.

Change :

`get_topchart($dbc, $var_ziekenhuis_id, $var_department_id);`

with

`$topchart = get_topchart($dbc, $var_ziekenhuis_id, $var_department_id);`

Comment: @CostCare read http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work